# How to use JCypher to send unrelated queries in one go and get the results properly

Tags: java, neo4j, java-13

I'm using JCypher 4.2.0 with Neo4J Server 4.0.2 with the builtin Movie graph.
I'm trying to unite couple simple, independent queries to one bigger for my needs.
first query: `MATCH (people:Person) RETURN people.name`, second query: `MATCH (m:Movie) WHERE m.title = "Apollo 13" RETURN m.title`.
and in JCypher:

```java
JcNode
        people = new JcNode("people"),
        m = new JcNode("m");
JcQuery
        query1 = new JcQuery(new IClause[]{
                MATCH.node(people).label("Person"),
                RETURN.value(people.property("name"))
        }),
        query2 = new JcQuery(new IClause[]{
                MATCH.node(m).label("Movie"),
                WHERE.valueOf(m.property("title")).EQUALS("Apollo 13")
                RETURN.value(m.property("title"))
        });
```

Of course, m.title should return only 1 result.
is it possible?